# How to move an object back and forth?

Tags: java

I'm trying to move an object back and forth. This is what i have tried, but it just moves right and stops but doesn't go back.

```
public void moveBug()
{   
    bugX++;

    if (bugX > 400){
        bugX--;
    }

    if (bugX < 0){
        bugX++;
    }
}
```

I also have this piece of code from my lecturer but I'm not sure how to apply it to the code.

```
if ((frameCount % 60) == 0)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your code unconditionally runs `bugX++` every time it's called which causes the bug to always move right. You'll need another variable to keep track of the direction the bug is moving. You need to do different things based on whether it's moving right or left..

- If it's moving right, increment x: `bugX++`.
- If it's moving left, decrement x: `bugX--`.
- If it reaches the right side, switch the direction to left.
- If it reaches the left side, switch the direction to right.